# Error group by on id in php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a sample database:

```
brand(id, name)
     (1, 'Apple')
     (2, 'Dell') 
model(id, name, brand_id)
     (1, 'Macbook', 1)
     (2, 'Iphone', 1)
     (3, 'Vostro', 2)
```

And php mysql code:

```
<?php
// Make a MySQL Connection
$query = "SELECT * FROM model";  
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error());
$brand_id = array();
$brand_id = array_unique($row['brand_id']);
?>    
<table>
    <?php for($i=0; $i<count(brand_id); $i++) {?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
    <tr/>
    <?php }?>
</table>
```

And result return 2 tr of 2 brand_id, but it show result all model name

```
<table>
   <tr><td>Macbook, Iphone, Vostro</td></tr>
   <tr><td>Macbook, Iphone, Vostro</td></tr>        
</table>
```

How to fix it to result is:

```
<table>
   <tr><td>Macbook, Iphone</td></tr>
   <tr><td>Vostro</td></tr>        
</table>
```

Comment: You haven't got a `GROUP BY` in your SQL.

Comment: Also do you mean: '<table>
   <tr><td>Macbook, Iphone</td></tr>
   <tr><td>Apple</td></tr>        
</table>
'?

Comment: IMHO `$row['brand_id']` is an integer rather than an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use an aggregate function, `GROUP_CONCAT`, for that:

```
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(b.`name`)
FROM    brand a 
            INNER JOIN model b
                on a.id = b.brand_id
GROUP BY a.`Name`
```

**[SEE HERE FOR DEMO @ SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/781be/2)**